# How can I change the styleshseet that my page is referring in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I want to be able to change the stylesheet in the `<link>` element through Angular2 (say, style2.css). Given that the  element is not part of the `<ng2-app>` element (the part that Angular2 manipulates), is this possible?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <ng2-app>

    <div class="loading">Loading&#8230;</div>
    <div style="text-align: center;clear: both;" class="md-headline">Application Loading....</div>

  </ng2-app>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 2 is using view Encapsulation to regulate how the stylesheets interact with each other.

```
 @Component({
 selector:'my-app'
 templateUrl:'card.html',
 styleUrls: ['stylesheet.css'],
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
 //encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
 //encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated is default 
})
```

To change the global stylesheet:

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rT7FagzWMOsQQay8ZkaO)

```
style(){

var link = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[0];
console.log(link.href);
link.href = "style2.css"; // or something else
console.log(link.href);

}
```

Comment: I want to change the stylesheet globally by manipulating `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` and without loading all CSS in `<style>` tags.